# "What have you tried?"...

Tags: discussion

Sometimes this "What have you tried" thing seems silly.

Take [this question [edit: question deleted/link broken]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2697485/product-comparison-inequality) for example. It's *obvious* that one should try to do it by induction, but it's not the same as asking how to prove $\sum_1^n j=n(n+1)/2$, in that it's not obvious, or at least it wasn't obvious to me, how to make the proof by induction work.

Supposing that's so, what would "I tried to do  it  by induction but I don't see how" have added? I gather that that would make the question more acceptable, but I really don't get it.

**Edit:** I've been told that's a senseless question because the answer is obviously "that would have added nothing". It was a rhetorical question, sorry.

**Next question:** Fine. Then what specifically *could* the OP have said, about *that question*, regarding what he'd tried, in order to show he'd worked on it?

That's rhetorical as well, although much less so, certainly less obviously so. I can't imagine anything specific the OP could have said along those lines. Here's why: I *did* spend a few minutes "working" on the question. Wasn't going to give it a lot of time, but I *did* *work* on it, cuz it pissed me off, seemed like something I should be able to do. But during the time I was working on it it  didn't happen once that I tried something that failed. It just wasn't that sort of difficulty - where I was stuck was thinking of something to try.

It's a fact that I did work on it, and it's a fact that if I hadn't seen the solution I'd be totally unable to give any evidence whatever that I'd worked on it.

**My point, for those to whom it's not clear, carefully phrased as a question:** Might it not be a good thing if before whining about "show your work" we stopped to consider that there is such a thing as working on a question without being able to produce evidence to that effect?

Supposing one agreed with that in principle, one could try to avoid asking unreasonable "what have you tried?" questions by making certain that before asking that one actually had at least a reasonable approach in mind. (In the question I'm talking about the guy who said "Try induction" more or less admitted when asked that he didn't see how to do it by induction. Suggesting induction as something that might work, fine, bbut suggesting as though it was clear it was something the OP should have tried but didn't, not fine *unless* we do see how it works.)

---

(So as to avoid answering questions from someone who really has no clue and hasn't  even considered induction, I posted an answer which it seems to me should  help only if the OP *is* thinking about induction...)

Comment: What's your question here?  It seems to be an essay (with scanty evidence or reasoning) that you believe "Sometimes this "What have you tried" thing seems silly."  If you have a question, please ask it. Else, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: BTW, meta is not intended to be a repository of editorials.  It's a Q&A site, as are all SE sites.

Comment: So what have you tried to do to solve this problem? Have you tried induction? :)

Comment: Not everyone who does mathematics is a man. Consider using gender neutral language such as "they" and "person" instead of "he" and "sir" when addressing or talking about other users.

Comment: @amWhy You can locate  the question by noting which sentence ends with the character "?".

Comment: Sarcasm isn't going to get you far.  And if that's your only question, that's senseless, and a misrepresentation of the question.

Comment: @amWhy Sarcasm? I had a question. I indicated it was a question using standard punctuation, and you nonetheless asked what the question was. Senseless? I don't see how  a __question_ can be senseless. Nobody's said anything remotely like an _answer_. The question _was_ the question - I don't see how it cann be a misrepresentation of itself.

Comment: I'm saying that, had the OP said "I tried to do it by induction but I don't see how"  it would have added nothing.  Had the OP made an effort, shown some work, added a definition or two, or specified what exactly has them tripped up, would have added a whole lot to the quality of the question.  Mind you, some of us repeat ten or more times each day the same lengthy comment template, with links and all, hoping to prompt a user to improve their question *so that it won't be closed*.  Your question, as I said, is senseless, because an asker stating what you suggest will not have improved the post

Comment: A few years ago I [suggested this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10962/11619). The gist is that anyone yelling WHYT should themself be able to answer the question fully, without breaking a sweat. That proposal never won much support. I guess that problems with the proposal are A) timing (speed is essential when closing a question because we have those answering machines), B) verification (may be having a sufficient number of upvotes in a relevant tag would be a good enough lithmus test?)

Comment: Basically the problem with  my proposal is that the number of questionable questions is so high that the implied workflow is not sustainable.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm absolutely with you on that. It may not be practicable to implement it as an official rule, but nonetheless people _should_  have a solution in mind before whining about WHYT. In that specific question for example I can't think of anything the OP _could_ have "tried".

Comment: @amWhy The point being that I can't imagine what else along the lines you suggest the OP _could_ have added. There are no  definitions to be added. Can you give a _specific_ hypothetical example of what the OP might have said, regarding _that_ question?

Comment: @amWhy Cuz I can't. I "worked" on it for a few minutes. While I was working on it it didn't happen once that I tried something that didn't work. I was trying to see how to relate "P(n+1)" to "P(n)", and simply didn't see how until I did. "Had the OP shown some work": I happened to see my notes just now. There _is_ no "work" there! There's the problem statement, and then the solution, with no indication of what heppened in the minutes in between. If I hadn't finally seen the solution there's no way I could give any evidence that I"d worked on the problem, even though I _did_.

Comment: @amWhy _You_ address borderline insulting comments to _me_, and when I simply reply I'm "targetting" you? Wow. I mean _really_, wow... I take it that no, you can't give a _specific_ example of something the OP could have said about that specific question in order to "show some effort"?

Comment: My own concern with "what have you tried" is that it is only part of what I really want to know, and often the least important part. I want to know why a question is interesting, if it isn't in a field I already know. I want to know where it came from and what problems it is related to. And, finally, I want to know how the OP thinks about the question and what methods they have at hand.  I find I'm not always happy with questions that include a token "My effort" without adding  genuine context.  I try to avoid asking "what have you tried", instead I like to link to "how to ask a good question"

Comment: In February, several editors also added advice on "Avoid no-clue questions" https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933 to the canonical "how to ask a good question" post,

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: the main concern I have with the proposal you suggested is that it is biased in favor of more "advanced" topics, while this site is supposed to be neutral about the level of math. On MathOverflow it makes perfect sense to favor advanced topics. But here, "How do I factor $x^2 + 2x + 1$",  "How do I prove that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a UFD", and "Why do elementary topoi have initial objects" should be treated as equivalent, in terms of the quality of post that we expect to accompany the question.  We should not try to filter questions by their level of math.

Comment: @CarlMummert Re your first comment: Excellent points. But it seems obvious to me why this specific question is interesting: If $b_j$ is close to $a_j$ then $\prod b_j$ should be close to $\prod a_j$. How close?

Comment: @CarlMummert Re your second comment: I was about to say that none of their suggestions for how to acquire a clue would have helped me with this specific question, when I realized that would be a lie: I was simply stuck until I decided to think about the case $n=2$.

Comment: @CarlMummert "We should not try to filter questions by their level of math:" I suppose not. But we can try to filter them based on how hard they should be to someone with the OP's background, to the extent that we can guess that.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich: as another example, the context given in the answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687983/prove-the-inequality-axbycz-sqrt-lefta2b2c2-right-leftx2y2z2-r/2688112#2688112  should have been included by the OP (or some context). The context - the relation with optics - is the reason for the question. Otherwise, it's just another random inequality.  // break // Of course, another reason we look for the OP in particular to provide context and motivation is to help filter out homework, in the sense that we allow homework-type problems that have well-motivated posts

Comment: Some older questions which seem related to the OP not being able show what they tried: [Suggested Guideline for “I Don't Know Where to Begin” Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17164) and [Homework, reasonable to have no clue?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26285)

Comment: This is redundant for people who were around for some time, but maybe it is worth reminding that there are various ways to add context, it does not necessarily mean OP's own attempt: [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959#9960) and [Can we stop the “Show your work craze”?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23169)

Comment: @CarlMummert Yes, it may be somewhat biased. Then again, I'm not seeing a flood of homework questions from a first course in category theory. Or, as [another user commented today](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2698135/11619) "very seldom is this site abused by people in chapter 22 of Vakil".

Comment: @amWhy As I earlier replied to a similar comment by someone else, no one is actively suggesting that everyone who does math is a male. It's just that we're accustomed to such usage. I'm an atheist, and I say 'Oh my God!' all the time.

Comment: I agree that there is some misusage of WHYT, but when I see a question without anything indicate that the OP tried something I do ask this in the comments because in case that OP **did** tried something I think that explaining what s/he did wrong can help more than explain an answer. If the OP sit on the question and can't think about a way, let's say it is the same as your example, I think s/he should add it because in that case I'll know to also add what to emphasize in my answer, for example, different ways to approach inductions and such. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Once again, a closure vote is not a super-disagree button. I'm voting to reopen because it is perfectly obvious what is being asked here, regardless of whether you like or dislike the premise.

Comment: @user296602 Voting to reopen what? If you mean this thread, I didn't even notice it had been closed. If you're referring to the question I'm talking about here, I might have voted to reopen. But, although I disagree with the reason for the close vote, that question does deserve to be closed because it's a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I was referring to this meta thread. There is a group of users here in meta who seem to use closure as a way to express disagreement. I see that my comment was vague and easily interpreted as being about the linked question on main - sorry about that!

Comment: @user296602 Right - for some reason I didn't see it was on hold until I refreshed the page. Yes, the idea that it's unclear what I'm asking is silly - good luck with that. It does seem curious that such a bad bad question should have so many more upvotes than downvotes. Raises the question of whether the upvoters are evil or just ignorant.

Comment: @user296602: I did not vote either way, but I do not think it's "perfectly obvious what is being ***asked*** here". For example, most (all?) of the interrogative statements in the posting are rhetorical, not questions meant to be answered.

Comment: Some of the moderators close good questions, questions that younger, less experienced mathematicians or students could benefit from, for no good reason.   Perhaps the mods forget what it’s like to be actively learning more basic concepts.  And If regular users are put in check by the mods, is there anyone out there to keep the mods in check?   Sometimes they're a little judgemental and assuming.

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy any specific examples?

Comment: This comment thread is as entertaining as it is predictable.  I love seeing WHYT questions in the Hot Meta Posts area.

Comment: @Amateur, I'm not sure you know what a moderator is. Moderators very very very rarely close questions: users who have the requisite number of points have the privilege of voting to close questions, and practically every time a question is closed it's because several users have voted to close it.

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy: To clarify GerryMyerson's comment, the "moderator tools" are available to [anyone with 10000 rep](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). Casting close votes can be done by anyone with 3000 rep. In the lingo of stackexchange, these people are not called moderators. The term "moderator" is reserved specifically to the handful of people with the ♦ symbol next to their name, such as [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen) above.

Comment: @Hurkyl thank you for that clarification.   Allow me, then, to redirect my ire at those who close good yet more basic questions at those with 3000 rep.

Comment: "where I was stuck was thinking of something to try" - Thank you. Honestly, it is endlessly frustrating when the situation is, "If I knew what to try, I would have tried it", and yet people insist on asking, "What have you tried?"

Comment: some people like myself (and sometimes the newcomers) are not too familiar in writing equations in mathjax .Its a time consuming process.If uploading picture would be allowed at a lower reputation ,then it would be easier to verify the said persons work, However this is just my opinion on this matter .

Comment: @JohnMa here's one that's about to be closed for no good reason https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2706943/419507

Comment: @JohnMa and another https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2706927/419507.  If you leave it up you help other people learn.

Comment: @amateurmathguy the first post is a clear duplicate and I voted to closed. Indeed in my comment i was questioning the closure by moderators, but since you have clarified my comment is moot.

Comment: @DRPR See, in the end it is your job, as the asker of the question, to ensure it attracts attention. If that is done through posting an image, then so be it. However, if you do consume the time of keeping the MathJax reference page next to you and even copying formulas from it, then you will be in a far better position to receive attention and better answers. On that note, I have seen your profile, and your questions are getting good attention, so you have probably seen the benefits of MathJax. That will keep you in good stead. As for other users, not using MathJax is at their jurisdiction.

Comment: WHYT means I know the answer and I am not going to tell you without a little pain. That said, my perspective on answering is (sadly) very influenced by the OP's style of interaction.

Comment: @JohnMa see the convo here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2717294/419507.  It was down voted to negative when I first saw this question

Comment: @JohnMa here's one people are just down voting without any explanation, and frankly I don't see why:   https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2717264/419507

Comment: Related: [new comment template](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28138)

Comment: "What have you tried?" is not silly when it MERELY means "What have you tried?".  But if it's an attempt to say "You shouldn't post homework questions when you don't have an actual question in your own mind?" then it's worse than silly. If that's what the commenter means, then the commenter ought to say that plainly.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt : I proposed that same "comment template" here on meta in my earliest days on stackexchange and it met with immense anger from nearly all of the users who are in the habit of closing newbies' questions.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/104041) needs a mention here.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I have taken, recently, to broadening my meager repertoire of responses to context-free questions beyond a bare "What have you tried?" because, in essence, I agree: There are plenty of times when that question just doesn't seem sensible.  The hardest task is occasionally just figuring out how to begin.  Alternatives to WHYT that sound reasonable to me include:

- What are you studying?
- What text is this drawn from, if any?  If not, how did the question arise?
- What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with?
- What kind of answer are you looking for?  Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else?
- Is this question something you think you should be able to answer?  Why or why not?

This list is not meant to be exhaustive, nor are all of them applicable to all questions, but I have found them useful options to keep in mind.

Comment: Right, the goal is not to humiliate the user who is generally confused about how to proceed, nor to drive them from the field, but to develop a rapport sufficient to achieve *mathesis* ([now rare](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mathesis)).

Comment: These are good alternatives. For some reason I can't quite articulate, "what have you tried?" seems to me appropriate only for straightforward questions or something similar to that (this impression seems to be shared by some of the community, from what I could gather from the comments). Your suggestions are more broadly appropriate (some more than others, of course).

Comment: Furthermore, they circumvent the issue that David points out: which is that "there is such a thing as working on a question without being able to produce evidence to that effect" (which I agree with). "What have you tried" seems to ask for *effort*, which sometimes is just noise and is arguably mostly an ethical requirement, whereas your suggestions seem to ask for *context*, which is what most of us can agree is the most important, I believe.

Comment: And consider also just helping them.  Spending too much time trying to get context you disregard the value of the question at face value.

Comment: Actually addressing the point I was trying to make, instead of replying as though I'd been insisting that every question should be given a complete and detailed answer regardless of "quality of question" issues - wow.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo ' For some reason I can't quite articulate, "what have you tried?" seems to me appropriate only for straightforward questions': Whether or not you can articulate the reason, that's an excellent articulation of what I was trying to say. In extreme cases the reason seems clear - if I have no idea what one _might_ try then asking the OP what he or she has tried seems obviously inappropriate.

Comment: @hardmath: Have you not yet realized that the rarity of mathematical thinking nowadays is **precisely because** mathematics students can easily cheat by outsourcing their homework and getting full solutions?

Comment: @user21820: That's plausible, and certainly tempting to believe, but for that very reason I distrust it; it has a bit too much of the "kids these days" feel.  It's almost impossible to demonstrate in any really convincing way, I think.  Are we even sure that it's rarer, or is it just that we're confronted more day after day by people who lack it? ¶ In any case, we can only deal with the situation in front of us.  I think WHYT is designed to elicit that sort of mathematical thinking; the challenge with it is often that it simply doesn't provide enough of a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: @BrianTung: I personally don't use "what have you tried". However, I have completely no sympathy for [serious cases of super-'entitled' askers like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2700612). As for convincing, I'm convinced because I've been on Math SE for a long time. I don't expect to convince others, but anyone is free to dig up the data and perform a statistical analysis.

Comment: Oh and when I was doing my undergraduate I personally witnessed many classmates outsource their homework to Yahoo Answers. This simply wasn't possible in the days before the internet.

Comment: @user21820: Of course.  I don't have much sympathy (if any) for such questions.  I'm convinced that such people exist, but I'm also convinced that they've always existed.  What I'm not convinced of (in either direction, yea or nay) is whether what we see is indicative of a general decline in mathematical thinking.  Most students still do not know of Math SE.  It's still pretty self-selecting.

Comment: In line with this answer, I would suggest to use something along the lines of "How did this question arise? Were you able to make any progress on it?" (Note how it is totally natural to reply to the second question that one did not manage to make any progress despite $x$ time units spent.)

Comment: +1 for the points you have raised. For the few questions I have asked here I have actually not shown my work, but rather added context as given in your points 2,3,4.

Comment: A possible context guess or short hint could help the OP more than a dry WHYT greeting.

Comment: I sometimes suggest the OP work out a simpler analogous problem.or a special case. This is often appropriate for combinatorial questions.

Comment: Related: [new comment template](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28138)

Comment: @Shaun  Please do not make a superficial edit to a post asked four years ago, in order to bump it! You already know such edits, adding three letters, serves no purpose other than in order to bump a post.

Comment: I contend that it is not superficial, @amWhy; I often copy & paste the questions listed above when asked what counts as context in some cases. I'm sick of having to edit in the "you".

Comment: You *don't have to*, Shaun, not when it is more disruptive than useful.  Feel free to go back a few weeks to "correct others grammar", but your edit is highly questionable, for years after it was posted.

Comment: Ehh, it's not a big deal @Shaun. I'd have made the edit myself if I had noticed (and am somewhat chagrined I didn't).

Answer (score 61):

The underlying problem, in my opinion, is the conception that one of the primary goals of MSE is

> Student arrives with an exercise and leaves with a solution.

In other words, one posts to MSE in order to outsource their mathematical exercises.

But this is (again in my opinion) an inappropriate use of the site! What we really want is something more like

> Student asks a question about mathematics and learns something, and maybe others learn too!

It's fine if an exercise prompted the question, and it's great if the student's new knowledge allows them to solve their exercise and future exercises as well, but the important thing is that the point of the interaction is to learn something mathematical!

---

The point of WHYT (in my opinion) is that if questioners post enough about their knowledge and thought processes, that answerers can divine the questions that *should* have been asked — the questions about learning mathematics that the questioners need — and proceed to answer that.

In other words, WHYT is meant as an aide. Rather than close a question outright, it is an attempt to help the questioner transform a question that is inappropriate for MSE into one that is appropriate for MSE, or at least implies an appropriate question.

If the only thing a user will provide is an exercise, then the question is simply inappropriate for MSE.

Comment: Incidentally, I share your dislike of WHYT, but for the opposite reason -- I don't think it's effective in its goal, and has the negative side effects of causing grief and perpetuating the conception that MSE is about arriving with exercises and leaving with solutions. But I'm out of touch with the current trends, so I can't claim confidently that its ineffective.

Comment: While I agree that it shouldn't be one, MSE has essentially become a homework help site. Not only do homework exercises not get closed, I usually can't even finish typing a hint for a 5-minute-old question before some whiz kid posts a solution with full details.

Comment: @user37208 Some elders too post solutions very quickly. Example - That Inequality Guy. (No offence)

Comment: If there is a natural tendency for MathSE to turn into a homework help site, then insisting that it must not do that is a good way to stay frustrated. The question is how to generate the most value, given that people are going to do what people naturally do.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: There is a natural tendancy for MathSE to turn into a spam repository too, but we do a pretty good job of fending that off. And it's not like its an impossible task to prevent a stackexchange site from being a do-my-work-for-me site, even one with our volume. Stackoverflow managed it, for example!

Comment: @Hurkyl Spot on! See my answer on how to provide a method to help achieve understanding instead of 'answer keys'.

Comment: @Hurkyl (2 comments up) I actually think Stack Overflow has the same problem. It's fairly common that I see someone post little more than an abstract problem description and get an answer with a full implementation; or someone posts a chunk of code that doesn't work, and answers consist of more chunks of code with bugs fixed and the style improved. In both cases I have to imagine that the asker and most readers learn little or nothing from the exchange.

Comment: You have nailed it with "WHYT is meant as an aide". As a Stack Overflow denizen who has landed here by accident, I'm happy to see this stance being advanced elsewhere on the network. (By the way, @DavidZ 's observation is also spot on.)

Comment: I think WHYT is simply an obstacle.

Answer (score 22):

In addition to the fact that we're not meant to do a person's homework for them, there's a more subtle reason to ask a question like that. Particularly for questions where the poster has just copied the homework question, it may not always be obvious what the context for the question is.

Typically, if you've got a homework question, you're supposed to apply something you've recently learned to solve it, but we don't know what class the poster is taking, let alone what material was most recently covered. The poster may be looking for something involving basic arithmetic but their question may also have solutions in Galois Theory, or Combinatorics, or Advanced Hypermathical Topomology, and it's not going to be helpful for the poster to offer the wrong one.

Answer (score 14):

I'm a frequent answer-er and basic homework hint-er on [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com). Perhaps some outsider perspective is useful here.

Do note that we have chosen for a very different attitude wrt 'homework' than math.se, for a good reason, in my opinion.

Our way to help the 'clueless' is the following procedure:

1. If it looks like a verbatim copy of homework, politely tell them they shouldn't just dump homework and expect us to solve it. Us solving their homework is unlikely to help them.
2. If it seems they have done something but are stuck and merely state confusion, ask them to clarify.
3. Okay, if it now is clear what the problem is an whether it is trivial, decide whether an answer or hint will help. Err on the side of hinting, answers will spoil the hints, but not the other way around. On CS, we usually hint in comments, as they aren't really answers.
4. Finally, if it seems this now look like a serious question, answer it!

Ideally, questions start at 1 or 2 and step by step become 3 or 4 and remain there. This takes a bit of back and forth, but seems to work well. Some are really helped by 3 (i.e. the hint has helped them to solve the question by themselves!) or other times they had a real serious question that has merely been badly asked and lead to 4. All this can be done before closing the question on CS.SE, but perhaps this is unsustainable on a site of your size.

Of course, people often get stuck at 1 or 2, but it isn't hard to advance to 3 or 4. It merely means you have to take your question and SE seriously. If you cannot do that then, well, you are better of without us.

Comment: It seems that in math.se a complete solution would be posted when the question was somewhere at stage 1 or 2. Then the question is unlikely to advance to stage 3,4. What would you guys do in CS.se to those questions?

Comment: @JohnMa This situation is indeed common on CS. At times, we give up and do nothing, but sometimes we post `Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/594)`.